# how to simplyfy this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where i have to join 2 table, how to simplify the following query

this is the organization table structure

```
table : organizations

 id name
   1   A
   2   B
   3   C
   4   D
```

this is the org_mapping table structure

```
table : org_mapping  mapping table structure

 id org_id service_provider_id
  1  1                      2
  2  4                      1


SELECT om.service_provider_id AS associated_with,
       o.name,
       o.logo,
       o.is_active            AS active
FROM   org_mapping om
       LEFT JOIN organizations o
              ON om.service_provider_id = o.id
WHERE  org_id = ?
       AND o.is_active = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT om.org_id   AS associated_with,
       o.name,
       o.logo,
       o.is_active AS active
FROM   org_mapping om
       LEFT JOIN organizations o
              ON om.org_id = o.id
WHERE  service_provider_id = ?
       AND o.is_active = 1
```

Is there anything i can make join outside the union,

If i give 2, i expect the output to be organization 1 and 4

Comment: These two `?` are the same value?

Comment: It depends on how you want to view the result.

Comment: @10086 yes, same values

Comment: You could do a conditional join. Just don't know what the condition would be.

Comment: Why are they the same queries? More specifically, what kinds of conditions are you wanting that you think you need to use a UNION ALL?

Comment: @clifton_h it is just one of those wacky things where he wants it, it makes sense, we have seen a lot wackier.

Comment: @Drew my job is not to answer exactly as he/she wants, it is to offer a solution that satisfies even what was not expected.

Comment: I rarely answer the question. I answer what the question should have been. a.k.a. talking to myself.

Comment: Your expected result is just a little weird, you give 2, then return 1,4. But `org_id` has no 2...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to view the result another way to do this

`Left Join` the `organizations` table twice to get the result but the data will present side by side where as `UNION` puts the data one after another

```
SELECT om.service_provider_id AS associated_with,
       o.name,
       o1.name
FROM   org_mapping om
       LEFT JOIN organizations o
              ON om.service_provider_id = o.id
       LEFT JOIN organizations o1
              ON om.org_id = o1.id
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use Subqueries for those LEFT JOIN tables?

Comment: @clifton_h - What is the need of `Sub-Query` here

Comment: Right, your query flattens the rows. We don't know the data. The `union all` would have retained dupes. That is gone now. The data strategy changes.

Comment: @Drew - I have clearly mentioned in answer it changes the way data is presented. Just a another way to view the result

Comment: Correct. It was an affirmation. I wasn't dumping on it. Perhaps the op can use it.

Comment: @Prdp Nothing wrong here, just was curious since `If i give 2, i expect the output to be organization 1 and 4` sounded like he wanted a more specific result.
You sorta beat us to writing a response. ;)